# How can I add users to different groups without using the AdminDjango

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I add users to different groups without using the Admin, I understand I have three types of users who choose what type they want to be at the time of registration, I already have the groups created with the different permissions, my question is as when I create the users through the registration plate, I also add them to the group that corresponds to it ???

this is what has been proven so far:

views.py

```
class FreeSignUpView(CreateView):
    model=CustomUser
    form_class = FreeSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def  get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type']='free'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user=form.save()
        login(self.request,user)
        return redirect('free_signup')
```

forms.py

```
class FreeSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    pais = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Pais.objects.all())
    anno = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profesion.objects.all())

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model=CustomUser
        fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("La direccion email ya existe")
        return email


    @transaction.atomic()
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_free=True

      #the error occurs when I try to add the user to the group
        group=Group.objects.get(name='free')
        group.user_set.add(user)

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

and it throws me the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRFQx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a django [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) that adds users to a group whenever a User is created.

```
def create_user_with_group(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.group = Group.objects.get(id=1) # replace this w/ however you add a user to your custom group
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_with_group, sender=User, dispatch_uid="create_user_with_group")
```

> More info: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html